# building bedroom in finished basement

Tags: flooring

I want to install 2 walls on top of floating laminate floor. Do I have to cut a channel in the floor or can I just fasten the walls to the floor. Do I have to fasten to the concrete below the laminate?

Answer (score 2):

A floating floor wants to be just that - not anchored down. If you go about placing the bottom plate for a stud wall on top of the flooring material and then try to use concrete nails to anchor the plate to the concrete floor the flooring will be captured and not longer able to float. This will result in constriction of the flooring material when it wants to move due to thermal and environmental changes and will likely warp, buckle and break joints between flooring planks.

BTW - In most places there will be a requirement for there to be an egress window in this basement bedroom to allow the occupant to exit in the case of fire. Unless you are prepared to provide that you may want to hold off on your remodeling project.

Comment: Without the egress window, you can call it an office or den, but don't put a bed or hide-a-bed in it. If someone is sleeping in it when there is a disaster, you're liable. The Building Official here told me one time when I was attempting to do this, "don't try to sell it in the future as a bedroom. The tax assessor knows how many bedrooms are in the house and they'll catch you for not getting Building Permit, etc.  if you go forward with code approved don't for get to add smoke detector by bedroom door  and install correct size egress window and at correct height.